# Trichotomy of well ordering

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I'm trying to prove trichotomy of well ordering and I have a question concerning the proof of the following fact: If $(A,\triangleleft_A)$ and $(B,\triangleleft_B )$ are two well ordered sets, then the following statements cannot be both true:
$$
\textbf{1.} \ \exists a\in A \  \text{s.t.} \ pred(A,a,\triangleleft_A)\cong (B,\triangleleft_B),\\
\textbf{2.} \ \exists b\in B \ \text{s.t.} \ (A,\triangleleft_A) \cong pred(B,b,\triangleleft_B).
$$
Likely wrong proof:

Suppose that $\textbf{1}$ and $\textbf{2}$ hold. Let us define the function $$g:pred(B,b,\triangleleft_B)\rightarrow pred(A,a,\triangleleft_A).$$ From $\textbf{1}$, since $\forall b'\in pred(B,b,\triangleleft_B)$,  we have $g(b')=a'$ with $a'\in pred(A,a,\triangleleft_A)$, then $g$ is injective. In general it is not surjective because an element of $pred(A,a,\triangleleft_A)$ can be mapped in $B\setminus pred(B,b,\triangleleft_B)$.

But now, if $a''\in pred(A,a,\triangleleft_A)$ is such that $g^{-1}(a'')=b$, can we say that the function 
$$
h:pred(B,b,\triangleleft_B)\rightarrow pred(A,a'',\triangleleft_A)
$$
is surjective and order preserving (taking advantage of the properties of $g$ and of the isomorphism in the hypothesis)? In such a case, since $h$ inherits the injectivity from $g$, it would be an isomorphism and, from $\textbf{2}$ we would get the contradiction:
$$
(A,\triangleleft_A) \cong pred(B,b,\triangleleft_B) \cong pred(A,a'',\triangleleft_A),
$$
that is, $(A,\triangleleft_A)$ would be isomorphic to an initial segment of itself.
I'm not able to prove that $h$ is indeed an isomorphism, maybe because it is not. Could you help me to find the mistake? (I hope this isn't too silly).
Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it is always a good idea to fix witnesses (even when they are unique!).  As (1) and (2) hold, let us fix order-isomorphisms $$\begin{gather}
f : ( B , \triangleleft_B ) \to \mathrm{pred} ( A , a , \triangleleft_A );
\\
g : ( A , \triangleleft_A ) \to \mathrm{pred} ( B , b , \triangleleft_B ).
\end{gather}$$  Consider the composition $gf : ( B , \triangleleft_B ) \to \mathrm{pred} ( B , b , \triangleleft_B )$.  Note that $gf$ is an order-isomorphism between $( B , \triangleleft_B )$ and its range.  It is relatively easy to show that the range of $gf$ is an initial segment of $( B , \triangleleft_B )$.  Since the range of $gf$ cannot be $B$, there is some $b_0 \in B$ such that $\mathrm{pred} ( B , b_0 , \triangleleft_B )$ is the range of $gf$.  It thus follows that $gf$ is an order-isomorphism between $( B , \triangleleft_B )$ and $\mathrm{pred} ( B , b_0 , \triangleleft_B )$, contradicting that no well-ordered set is order-isomorphic to a (proper) initial segment!

Comment: Thank you and my compliments for the clarity. Anyway, was my reasoning workable in your opinion (even if non elegant)?

Comment: @the_elder: One bit of concern is that going from the initial segments outward to the entire well-ordered set might cause problems.  It seems to me that your mapping $g$ would first look at where $b^\prime \in \mathrm{pred}(B,B,\triangleleft_B)$ went into $(A,\triangleleft_A)$, and then map this image back into $(B,\triangleleft)$.  However this requires knowing that the first image of $b^\prime$ is in $\mathrm{pred}(A,a,\triangleleft_A)$, which would require more justification (perhaps even the result being proved!).

Comment: mmh... I understand. 
my attempt was too twisted. simpler reasonings are always better.

Comment: @user642796 Am a bit confused isn't the range of $g\circ f$ just $\{b\in B: b<g(a)\}$?