# Why is the minimal uncountable well-ordered set $S_{\Omega}$ unique?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

In section 10 of *Topology* by Munkres, the minimal uncountable well-ordered set $S_{\Omega}$ is introduced. Furthermore, it is remarked that,

> Note that $S_{\Omega}$ is an uncountable well-ordered set every section of which is countable. Its order type is in fact uniquely determined by this condition.

However, how to justify its uniqueness?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This stems from the fact that given two well-ordered sets $X, Y$ exactly one of the following holds ([see this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/332793/8348)):

1. $X$ is order-isomorphic to $Y$;
2. There is a (unique) $a \in X$ such that $\{ x \in X : x < a \}$ is order-isomorphic to $Y$; or
3. There is a (unique) $b \in B$ such that $\{ y \in Y : y < b \}$ is order-isomorphic to $X$.

So suppose $X$ is another well-ordered set which is *not* order-isomorphic to $S_\Omega$.  Then either

- there is a (unique) $b \in S_\Omega$ such that $\{ y \in S_\Omega : y < b \}$ is order-isomorphic to $X$, and since  $\{ y \in S_\Omega : y < b \}$ is countable, it follows that $X$ is also countable.
- there is a (unique) $a \in X$ such that  $\{ x \in X : x < a \}$ is order-isomorphic to $S_\Omega$.  But then $\{ x \in X : x <_X a \}$ is itself an initial section of $X$ which is uncountable.

So any well-ordered set which is not order-isomorphic to $S_\Omega$ is either countable, or has an uncountable proper initial section.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two uncountable ordinals.  Suppose further that for every $\gamma<\alpha$, $\gamma$ is countable.  Likewise, suppose that for very $\eta<\beta$, $\eta$ is countable.  You want to show that $\alpha=\beta$.

Suppose that $\alpha<\beta$.  Then $\eta=\alpha$ is uncountable, and satisfies $\eta<\beta$.  This is a contradiction.  Thus $\alpha\not<\beta$.  Likewise $\beta\not<\alpha$.